# Unable to start derby network server

Tags: derby

I am in the derby bin folder. Executed the . setNetworkServerCP command. Now when I try to use command startNetworkServer it shows command not found.
I also tried to execute the java command as follows:

```
java -jar lib/derbynet.jar start
```

However, I am getting this error:

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
> org/apache/derby/drda/NetworkServerControl has been compiled by a
> more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0),
> this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Please help me. I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: It seems you may need a newer Java or an older Derby.

Comment: Thank you. I tried with derby 10.14 it is working now.

Answer (score 3):

Derby version 10.15 supports Java version 9 and higher.

Derby version 10.14 supports Java version 8.

Since java version 9 is classfile version 53, it seems that you are trying to run Derby 10.15 using Java version 8.

So either switch to Derby 10.14, or move to Java 9+.